# Eclipse CDT can't resolve a structs function when accessed from a std::map

Tags: c++, eclipse, dictionary, struct

The situation is as follows: I declare a struct in a header file, and in the accompanying source file I put instances of this struct in a `std::map<int, myStruct>`.

The code compiles and runs fine, but Eclipse does'nt recognize the function call and keeps it underlined red (can not open declaration either).

Example code:

```
//myClass.h
struct myStruct{
  int returnValue(){
    return 4;
  }
};

// other class parameters here
```

and in the source

```
//myClass.cpp

#include "myClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using std::map;

int main(){

  //create map with struct and assign
  map<int, myStruct> myMap;
  myStruct exampleStruct;
  myMap[3]=exampleStruct;

  //access struct via [] map operator
  std::cout << myMap[3].returnValue() << "\n";  //this line flagged by Eclipse, but works

  return 0;

}
```

Is this behavior of Eclipse known, or is my config wrong?

Also, on a side note, I am not a professional progammer, so style advice etc is very welcome :)

EDIT: fixed typos in myClass.h and myClass.cpp

Comment: I never worked with eclipse, but does it change anything, if you make it a `class` instead of `struct` (and declare the method as `public`) ? Also, I could imagine, that ecplise wants the filename to be the same as the class name, but again its just a blind guess.

Comment: @tobi303 never tried a class, but since other class functions are not flagged, I assume Eclipse won't mind. Also, Eclipse does not care for the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing typos, the code is fine and is accepted without even a warning. So I only imagine that it could be a problem in Eclipse configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is embarrassing. I ran the sample code through eclipse (the real example is very long and depends on some custom libraries) and Eclipse had no issue with the function of the struct inside the map.

So I rebuilt the index of the real project, and now everything is fine. Strange, because Eclipse always seemed to update the index when I created a new class, but not this time... so thanks to all who read and answered, but the problem is solved already.